# "User memory limit exceeded" during Random Forest classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, random-forest

I succeeded in an initial attempt at using Random Forest classification on my input image (an exported mosaic covering ~ 2,797 km2). I used 30 trees, classified based on 4 bands, and passed a training set that included 251 polygons that covered ~3 km2. I wanted to refine the outputs, so I added training polygons in an attempt to have the training set cover 0.25% of the total study area (65 polygons per class @ 1.4 km2 each ~= 7 km2).

After boosting my training set and re-importing, I now get a `"User memory limit exceeded"` error. I have tried adding a `tileScale` property to my `image.sampleRegions()` parameters, but this does not solve the issue:

```
var imageName = ee.Image(".../201808image");

//Set visualization parameters for PlanetScope tiles
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['b3', 'b2', 'b1'],
  min: 250,
  max: 1452,
  gamma: 1.0
};

//Set up supervised classification - use all PlanetScope bands.
var bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'];
var p = [
  '369b47', //forest
  'b76031', //low veg
  'cc0013', //built up
  'cdb33b', //tilled land
  'aec3d4' //water
];

//Load training dataset
var trainSet = ee.FeatureCollection('.../TrainingSet');

//Overlay polygons and begin training
var training = imageName.sampleRegions({
  collection: trainSet,
  properties: ['Class'],
  scale: 3,
  tileScale: 16
});

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(30).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'Class', 
  inputProperties: bands
  });
print('Random forest, explained', classifier.explain());

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = imageName.classify(classifier);
print('Image classified!');

//Add image created from PlanetScope tiles to map
Map.addLayer(imageName, vizParams, 'PlanetScope imagery 201808');
print('Image added.');
Map.addLayer(trainSet, {color: 'aqua'}, 'Training Polygons');
print('Training polygons dataset added.');
Map.addLayer(classified, {palette: p, min: 0, max: 4}, 'land cover');
print('Classified layer added.');
```

How do I get around the user memory limit that I am exceeding?

I get the impression people use GEE to process much larger image datasets. I am unclear if there is something with my training polygon Feature class or in the creation of SampleRegions that I should be changing.

Comment: Update: I thought it might be an issue of the number of points being created by `image.sampleRegions`, as they seem to suggest in the video [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification) that classifiers can only handle up to one million points. To try and find how many pixels my training polygons contained, I used `print(training.aggregate_histogram("band_order"));`. My original TrainingSet had ~1,108,000 pixels. I reduced the number and size of my training polygons and arrived at ~990,000 pixels. Still the same "User memory limit exceeded" error.

Comment: Is the image you are using 3m spatial resolution and is this the full code you are trying to run or are there other parts? Because of the order in which Earth Engine runs things, the issue may be elsewhere. You could test increasing the scale parameter in sampleRegions to try and isolate if that is where the issue is occurring.